# What shall I do with "unexpected indentation" errors pointing do .rb files? after migrating from rails 3 to 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

EDIT: added the ".rb" example and further doc

EDIT2: added lost stacktrace

EDIT3: I can't reproduce the first one with favicon_link_tag('logo_16.png')

I get "unexpected indentation" errors - **after migrating rails from 3.2 to 5.0**

ok, I expected many problems, but I have no idea where to put or to solve this: get indentation error where the stack points to .rb files, that's spooky.

```
Showing c:/rbstart/app/views/layouts/cibo_lista.haml where line #31 raised:

SyntaxError: [stdin]:68:1: unexpected indentation
Extracted source (around line #645):

            @page_css.uniq!
            TechDraw::DrawLogger.add_file(:css, @page_css)
    645     r=get_page_css_manifest.uniq.map { |css| stylesheet_link_tag css  }.join("\n").html_safe <--- unexpected indentation error?
            # following is my temp. solution
            # r=get_page_css_manifest.uniq.map { |css| "<link href='/assets/#{css}' media='screen' #rel='stylesheet'/>"}.join("\n").html_safe
            clear_page_css

Rails.root: c:/rbstart

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/helpers/site_tags_helper.rb:645:in `block in site_css_link_tag'

app/helpers/site_tags_helper.rb:645:in `block in site_css_link_tag'
app/helpers/site_tags_helper.rb:645:in `map'
app/helpers/site_tags_helper.rb:645:in `site_css_link_tag'
app/views/layouts/cibo_lista.haml:31:in `_app_views_layouts_cibo_lista_haml___421072769_123879800'
config/application.rb:171:in `call'
config/application.rb:171:in `block in <class:TemplateRenderer>'
app/controllers/ldc/cibo_lista_controller.rb:373:in `render'
lib/site_base/site_exceptions.rb:37:in `render_all_errors'
lib/sweet_check.rb:33:in `call!'
lib/sweet_check.rb:19:in `call'
```

The full trace leads to the middle of nowhere

Can someone explain me what happen here?

(edit) for me it looks as if this `stylesheet_link_tag` get somehow again though HAML?

Comment: I think I never seen an indentation error in a ruby file. Ruby is not indentation-sensitive.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: me too, that why I meant "spooky". I know that Ruby won't raise indentation exeptions.

Comment: The error you posted, it says the file is called `cibo_lista.haml`, which is not a ruby file. Do you have big chunks of ruby in that haml file?

Comment: oh, forgot the rest of the stack trace. And there are some helper calls and if's

Comment: explanation here -> [unexpected-indentation-error-with-favicon-tag-after-migration-to-rails-5-0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40726338/unexpected-indentation-error-with-favicon-tag-after-migration-to-rails-5-0)

Comment: I solved the riddle here [unexpected-indentation-error-with-favicon-tag-after-migration-to-rails-5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40726338/unexpected-indentation-error-with-favicon-tag-after-migration-to-rails-5-0)

Comment: I "solved" this here [unexpected-indentation-error-with-favicon-tag-after-migration-to-rails-5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40726338/unexpected-indentation-error-with-favicon-tag-after-migration-to-rails-5-0/40727722#40727722)

Comment: solved here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40726338/unexpected-indentation-error-with-favicon-tag-after-migration-to-rails-5-0/40727722

Answer (score 1):

> indentation errors pointing to .rb files

That's not an .rb file, that's a .haml file.

> what shall I do

Fix the indentation. HAML docs say:

> Haml’s indentation can be made up of one or more tabs or spaces. However, indentation must be consistent within a given document. Hard tabs and spaces can’t be mixed, and the same number of tabs or spaces must be used throughout.

There's probably a mix of tabs and spaces there. Make sure there is no mix.

Comment: I don't like to vote down answers, but you completely ignored the "after migrating from Rails 3.2 to Rails 5.0, and "The indentation is ok, worked for a long time."

Comment: @halfbit: Are you positive that the migration caused no changes in these lines? In this case, I'm betting on too big indentation. Looks like 4 spaces. What if you indent with 2 spaces (as is ruby de-facto standard and, I think, in haml too).

Comment: I _was_ sure, because my editor shows the "tabs" and the blanks (because of this indentation probs), the point I cant reproduce the error any more, plz, make an edit to your answer, so I can remove the downvote

Comment: @halfbit What was your solution please

Comment: @stujo not migrating :( I had other probs, too

Answer (score 1):

While Upgrading rails 3 to 5

For me this was because there was an exception being thrown in the coffeescript pre-processor, but I would imagine this could also happen in stylesheet processing too

```
Showing /app/views/layouts/application.html.haml where line #22 raised:

SyntaxError: [stdin]:15:1: unexpected indentation

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
(execjs):7539:12
(execjs):7543:21
(execjs):1:46
app/views/layouts/application.html.haml:22:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_haml__1205581402263291548_70330813935540'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:240:in `block (2 levels) in render_404'
```

Running

```
bin/rails assets:precompile
```

Reproduces the problem but identifying the source was a process of trial an error by removing half the items (binary search) at a time from application.js (or application.css)

The line number reported [stdin]:15:1 was accurate without the filename it wasn't much help

Was able to install coffeelint ( https://github.com/clutchski/coffeelint/blob/master/doc/user.md )

But I suspect having support for this in the editor would greatly reduce wasted time